# BroadcastReceiver not called on bluetooth pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

Very simple. the only code I have is this :

```
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Log.d(TAG,"Device "+mDevice.getName()+" Was Found");
            }
        }
    };
```

but this is not called when I pair a device . why ?

Comment: have you registered your broadcast receiver in Manifest file?

Comment: @Avi no. how to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you need to register you broadcast receiver for following filters

```
ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED
```

and then in onReceive

add them like this

```
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
            mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (mDevice .getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            //means device paired
        }

   }
```

Read more Here [Bluetooth Device Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#BOND_BONDED)

```
int     BOND_BONDED     //Indicates the remote device is bonded (paired).
int     BOND_BONDING    //Indicates bonding (pairing) is in progress with the remote device.
int     BOND_NONE   //Indicates the remote device is not bonded (paired).
```

**Edit:** after last Comment

you also need to add

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Hi . the only actions I get is ACL_CONNECTED followed by ACL_DISCONNECTED right after

Comment: again I for some reason don't get the STATE_CHANGED action , only ACL_CONNECTED followed by ACL_DISCONNECTED

Comment: you misunderstood me . I Log the actions I get in the onReceive and the only actions I receive is the ones I mentioned. meaning the if in your answer is never true

Comment: oh sorry then. do you add filter to your broadcast receiver.like this IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED); registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

Comment: In the intent filter, I believe BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED should actually be BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: You forgot to handle the `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING` state before. The immediately check of the bond state within the BluetoothDevice instance will result in `BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE`.
So first extract those info `val bondState = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BOND_NONE)`. You can only trust those value.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the permission in the manifest ??

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: ok then print the action that you retrive and make sure the action name that you retrived  is equal ACTION_FOUND

Comment: and make sure that you have registerd your broadcast ,,
example :
IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, filter1);

Answer (score 0):

From android 6.0 and greater you need to check additional permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  in order to fetch list.
without this you onReceive method with ACTION_FOUND will not call.